# arcpy 'Feature Layer' conversion to 'KML file' doesn't do anything (doesn't even throw error)

Tags: arcpy, kml, arcgis-pro

I have built a small arcpy script to convert feature classes into kml files (kmz in fact).

```
import arcpy
import os
import datetime

working_folder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

#Creating the path where the output kmz files will be written
date = datetime.date.today()
out_folder_name = 'Wibre Network ' + str(date)
out_path = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\KML files', out_folder_name)

#Input variables.
fc_Opt_All = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Optimity_All')

#feature class path
fc_node_live_available = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Node_Live_Available')

#kmz file path
kml_node_live_available = os.path.join(out_path, 'Node_Live_Available.kmz')

#Conversion
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Opt_All, 'fl_Opt_All')
query = "ESTATE LIKE '{0}' AND STATUS LIKE '{1}'".format('Node Live','YES')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('fl_Opt_All', 'NEW_SELECTION', query)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('fl_Opt_All', fc_node_live_available)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_node_live_available, 'fl_node_live_available')
arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion('fl_node_live_available', kml_node_live_available, is_composite = 'NO_COMPOSITE', ignore_zvalue = 'ABSOLUTE')
```

The script doesn't throw any error. However, it doesn't produce any output.
I have double checked the feature class created after the query (fc_node_live_available) and it's NOT empty.

Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: Have you checked that the feature layer 'fl_node_live_available' is not empty, for example with get Count?

Comment: How many features are in layer 'fl_node_live_available'?  GetCount can tell you.

Comment: I have checked that feature class 'fc_node_live_available' is not empty, but I wouldn't know how to check whether feature layer 'fc_node_live_available' is empty or not.

Comment: `print arcpy.GetCount_management('fl_node_live_available').getOutput(0)` will tell you the number of features in the layer

Comment: GetCount shows that 'fl_node_live_available' contains 59 objects, which is the expected number.

Comment: It does not even produce the kmz file or is it empty? Have you checked that `kml_node_live_available` looks like a valid path+filename with print? Try replacing it with path and name in text: `r"C:\folder\file.kmz"`

Comment: You pointed me to the cause of the problem. It seems that 'LayerToKML_conversion' does not produce output if the folder does not exist (which was the case). Strange thing is that it doesn't give an error at all.

Comment: If I write the output kmz file to an existing folder then it works.